# Google Search Appliance: Limiting Number of Results

Tags: search, gsa

I am attempting to limit the number of results that are displayed as a result of [dynamic result clustering](http://code.google.com/apis/searchappliance/documentation/62/xml_reference.html#DynamicResultClustersClusterURLParameter) on the Google Search Appliance. I've looked through the XSLT, but I've only come across the following two user-modifiable options:

```
<!-- *** dyanmic result cluster options *** -->
<xsl:variable name="show_res_clusters">1</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="res_cluster_position">right</xsl:variable>
```

Are there more options that I'm unaware of that I could use to limit the results? Is there another way that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. You simply edit out the XSLT that generates the HTML for where the results are rendered. I tried this yesterday, but it didn't work (not sure what is different about today).